# Generating code from yaml - more reliable than Swagger codegen?

Tags: maven-3, swagger-codegen, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

## (Sample) Problem:

When a yaml source contains conflicting definitions, e.g. `myClass` and `MyClass` both generating into a java class `MyClass` with one overwriting the other, no warning or error occurs.
Other similar cases can occur the same way (e.g. via implicitly generated classes from complex entries of `type: array`).

## Framing

- has to work without modifying the source file

  - there is exactly one source file, for whatever that's worth
- has to work as a Maven plugin

  - tested with `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` 2.4.0 and 2.4.22
- am familiar with JAXB2 and both of its common Maven plugins:

  - `jaxb2-maven-plugin`
  - `maven-jaxb2-plugin`
- am not familiar with `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`
- did not find solutions (or even corresponding problem reports) using Google searches

  - `swagger codegen strict`
  - `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin strict`
  - `swagger codegen name collision`
  - `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin name collision`
  - `swagger codegen resolve name collision`
  - `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin resolve name collision`
- found [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5410) closed issue describing a similar issue (silently generates corrupt code), which appears to be mostly unrelated and is alledgedly long fixed

## Question

What is the proper solution that produces

- an eagerly failing generation process
- amended via externally configured `customBindings`
- without touching the `yaml` source file

?

## Solution ideas:

### Use JAXB2 instead

JAXB2

- fails generation where a generated file already exists
- allows a separate `customBindings.xjs` file to modify generation of
  classes
- can be adapted to work with YAML using
  `JacksonJaxbYAMLProvider`

However it seems that the common Maven plugins `jaxb2-maven-plugin` and `maven-jaxb2-plugin` do not support YAMl definition files (out of the box?). [1]

### Use Mustache files to resolve the name collision

The [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) language seems to provide the necessary facilities to implement rules similar to JAXBs `xjb`.

However

- binding a Mustache template to a class has to be done **by name** (`<class name>.mustache`), aka. name collision in particular cannot be resolved from an external file [2]
- this does not help with the **silence** of errors in generated code - one cannot fix the error, while unaware of it

1 - Searches for this topic have yielded one result that it does not work out-of-the-box (duh) and no results whether it can be made to work using the `extensions` interface both plugins support.

2 - I could not find the relevant part directly within Swagger codegen documentation, but [here](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating/) is a relevant part of the implemented-by-Swagger OpenAPI generator documentation.

Comment: I was tempted to tag `java` and `yaml` for the required input and output languages respectively, but both tags require the question to be about some feature of the language, which this one is not about. So I left them out.

Comment: I feel the question title requires improvement but could not come up with a better one.
`Swagger codegen - make silent errors visible`, `Swagger codegen - name collision` are more precise regarding the sample problem, but given that I want a `fail-fast` behaviour regardless of specific error, those might attract answers too focused on what is merely an example.
Suggestions welcome.